# How to download localization file in the first launch of the android application

Tags: android, localization

i have a query regarding location files. i want to download localization files from a server (string.xml, string_ar.xml , etc) on the launch of the android application instead of declaring previously. is there any way to achieve this task..

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, not if you want to use the default Android localisation support. You'll need to add the strings to your APK.

Comment: instead of adding it to values -> string_qualifiers, i want that files from server and save it to the values folder. so ur saying that it is not possible at all.

Comment: Nope. If you need "dynamic localisation loading", you'll need to use another library or write your own function for that. You can't manipulate the contents of the `res/`-folder after the application is compiled.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know that the app is running for the first time, you could save a boolean value in the preferences. Something like `first_run`.

If you download localization files you will not be able to use the default localization support.
(Not sure why you wouldn't just place them in the apk)

What you could do is getting the localization and hitting the server for the correct translations.
You could create your own class that takes care of getting strings and if they do not exist, fail over the android one.

Something like:

```
public static String getString(Context ctx, int key) {
  String ret = getStringFromDB(key);
  if ( ret == null ) {
    ret = ctx.getString(key);
  }

  return ret;
}
```